# Getting a JSON from an API with fetch js

Tags: javascript, get

I just don't know what is wrong. I am trying to get a JSON from an API with fetch in JavaScript. This is the code:

```
function get(){
      fetch('http://localhost:8082/marca/listar', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {},
            mode: 'no-cors', // <---
            cache: 'default'
        })
        .then(Response => { return Response.json() })
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data.nombre)
        });

}
```

[image: This is the url of the api]

And I get the following error:

[image: console message image]

Comment: Can you post the error that you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

Per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json have you tried:

```
response.json().then(data => {
  // do something with your data
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it is because the response you get from the server is an array not JSON object 
so treat it as such

Answer (score 0):

```
fetch('http://localhost:8082/marca/listar', 
{ cache: 'default' })
  .then(function (response) {
    if (response.status !== 200) {
      return;
    }
    response.json().then(function (data) {
      data.forEach((element) => {
        element.whatYouWant; /* Change (whatYouWant) to your desired output */
      })
    })
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
  });
```